Creating a python-for-android recipe for a package having a C module
The Enthought traits package has a traits.c file to be compiled. I want to use it in an android app using buildozer.
I tried the following simple recipe:
from pythonforandroid.recipe import PythonRecipe
from pythonforandroid.toolchain import current_directory, shprint
import sh

class TraitsRecipe(PythonRecipe):
    version = '6.3.2'
    url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/traits/traits-{version}.tar.gz'
    depends = ['setuptools', 'numpy']
    site_packages_name = 'traits'
    call_hostpython_via_targetpython = False

    def install_python_package(self, arch):
        with current_directory(self.get_build_dir(arch.arch)):
            hostpython = sh.Command(self.hostpython_location)
            env = self.get_recipe_env(arch)
            
            # Perform the installation of the traits package
            install_dir = self.ctx.get_python_install_dir(arch.arch)
            shprint(hostpython, 'setup.py', 'install', '--root={}'.format(install_dir), _env=env)
            
recipe = TraitsRecipe()

The problem is that in my android app, the package is put in _python_bundle/site-packages/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/traits instead of _python_bundle/site-packages/.
In my app, I can move the folder and then I can use traits, but there should be a simple change in the recipe that makes the package be installed in the right location.
